# Create copy of excell sheet with code problems.

Tags: excel, copy, vba

Created a sheet in excel in which when new information is needed I will simply create a copy of the worksheet into a new tab. However I have a code that allows me to clear certain cells or erase them to enter the data, it goes as:

```
Sub Clear_Cells()

Range("B5").ClearContents
Range("C5").ClearContents
Range("D5").ClearContents
Range("E5").ClearContents
Range("F5").ClearContents
Range("B8").ClearContents
Range("C8").ClearContents
Range("E8").ClearContents
Range("C9").ClearContents
Range("C13").ClearContents
Range("C14").ClearContents
Range("D13").ClearContents
Range("D14").ClearContents
Range("E15").ClearContents
Range("B18").ClearContents
Range("C18").ClearContents
Range("D18").ClearContents
Range("E18").ClearContents
Range("F18").ClearContents
End Sub
```

The problem is when I create a new page and try to clear the cells in that page it always clears the cells of the original page. I know it has to be something simple but just cannot put finger on it.

Comment: You need to make a reference to the worksheet you are trying to clear the values.

Comment: Use `Sheets("NewSheet").Select` or `Worksheets("NewSheet").Activate` before executing clearing task.

Comment: Let's say your new sheet's name is "Sheet4", so the correct reference to clear it's contents should be `Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B5").ClearContents`

Comment: How are you calling/running the code?  From another sub or manually or by `Button_Click`?

Comment: I have a button click,

Comment: Want I want is a master copy of a spreadsheet that is blank, then the user can create a copy of the master sheet and fill out information. Then the user will need to make a copy of the copy to create a new sheet. I need it this way because I want all the new sheets tabs to be on the left side. So when they create a copy of the copy I need them to click the button to delete the previous information so they can enter in fresh data.

Comment: Where is the code located? Is it in a specific sheet or a workbook module?